# Select2 v4 Result does not show in the dropdown

Tags: php, json, ajax, autocomplete, jquery-select2

What could be wrong in the code below?
I'm using Select2 version 4, when there's no result the **No result** dropdown shows,
But when there's result nothing shows (The dropdown does not show).

```
function formatProduct(product) {
    if (product.loading) return product.text;
    var markup =  '<div class="product-to-compare" data=' + product.id + '>' + product.text + '</div>' ;
    return markup;
}
function formatProductSelection(product) {

    return product.name || product.text;
}

$(".select-category").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/autocomplete",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
    };
},
processResults: function (data, params) {
  params.page = params.page || 1;

  return {
    results: data.items,
    pagination: {
      more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
  }
};
},
cache: true
},
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  templateResult: formatProduct,
  templateSelection: formatProductSelection
});
```

In the result from php script I have something like this:

```
{"items":{"id":12,"text":"Sport"}}
```

But the dropdown does not show, is there something wrong I'm doing?

Comment: There's no `data.total_count` returned in your result

Comment: @apokryfos that doesn't make any different. adding `data.total_count` to the json or removing this from the JS `pagination: {
      more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
  }`

Comment: Try using `pagination: { more: false }`

Comment: I don't know if this really has anything to do with the dropdown display. But it does not make any different, either set to false or adding `total_count` to the json result

Comment: Well check your browser console. The fact that you were using `data.total_count` while it did not exist would have caused a JavaScript error .